# Want to remove the white line between Section and first cell in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

As you can see on screenshot, this is really annoying.
There are source code in screenshot :).
How can i remove it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's much easier to see what is happening if you just copy and paste code into the question. A screenshot is not very useful as it can't be copied (if we want to edit it) and it can't be searched on Google or StackOverflow.

Comment: It's not a line, It's default separator of `UITableView`. You can remove it by setting separator style as none from storyboard and programatically `yourTBLName.separatorStyle = .None`.

Comment: I just tried but it does not work. do you know any other solution?

Comment: This isn't really helpful (at all) and isn't something you should be asking here simply because it could be a multitude of things, completely unrelated to the screenshot and we would never know, short of debugging the code ourselves. Spend some time debugging and inspecting the view hierarchies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at the background color for your cell with the identifier "AlertSectionTypeCell." It looks like you have set the background color of your cell's content view instead of the background color of the cell itself.

I expect that the white line that you are seeing is the result of the cell's view's background color being set to "Default." Try:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AlertSectionTypeCell") as! GMAlertsTypeTVCell
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: I have solved at Nov, last year....
You are right, it was background color issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you're looking for is...

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .None
```

That should remove the separator.

Comment: I just tried but it does not work. do you know any other solution?