# Removal of white line under section header in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm struggling with removing the white lines below each custom section header in an UITableView, as seen below. Any suggestions? I already use this in my TableView.

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

The above solves only the separators between the cells, not for the headers.

The only thing I have in my custom section header is

```
containerCellView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 24/255.0, green: 34/255.0, blue: 41/255.0, alpha: 100)
```

[image]

Comment: Please show your code for header

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925115/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-separator-line-from-a-uitableview

Comment: Did you use a UITableViewCell for your header ? The code you provide in your edit is not responsible of showing a header.

Comment: Until you give more code you'll get bad answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to remove the white line between Section and first cell in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801330/want-to-remove-the-white-line-between-section-and-first-cell-in-ios)

Answer (score 2):

Set heigth for header & footer to 0.01 it will solve your problem

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

            return 0.01

    }
```

Comment: I use my headers, so I better not set the height to that?

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: give me a minute,i'll test it and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Use this code were you set your header

```
 headerView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;         
 headerView.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
```

Comment: you have set  [UIColor blackcolor];

Comment: Doesn't work, since it's not really a seperator I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was the backgroundColor of my header cell that caused the problem.

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Solved the problem in the custom header class

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce similar issue on iPhone 7 Plus/iOS 12.1. I have a class conforming to `UITableViewDelegate` and `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` is implemented like that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0 // any float value
}
```

I added `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:)` to fix the problem:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0 // any float value
}
```

All code in this post was tested in Xcode 10.2.1. I used Swift 5.